# Программа не видит .jsp, ошибка 404

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

Не хотел чтобы мой первый вопрос на этом сайте был таким глупым, но я уже второй день туплю над этой проблемой.
В рамках своего самообучения делаю нубский crud-проектик, опираясь на [это](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2253-znakomstvo-s-maven-spring-mysql-hibernate-i-pervoe-crud-prilozhenie-chastjh-1#Model-View-Controller). Maven, Spring, Hibernate, DAO, TomCat. Понимаю, что метод устаревший, но для начала мне норм. В моем варианте делаю телефонную книгу.
Проблема всплыла в самом конце - кнопка "edit" ведет на 404 вот с таким сообщением:

> JSP file [/edit/WEB-INF/views/editPage.jsp] not found

При том, что кнопка "add" (страничка которой находится в той же директории) работает корректно и ведет куда надо.
Изначально я пробовал делать как автор гайда - сделать одну страничку и на add, и на edit, а уже потом разделил на две разных, чтобы быть уверенным, что проблема не в ней.

[image: Структура проекта]

Ниже немного кода.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>borkaugroups</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoneDirectory</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>14</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.37</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Контроллер:

```
package borkaugroup.phonedirectory.controller;

import borkaugroup.phonedirectory.model.Subscriber;
import borkaugroup.phonedirectory.service.SubscriberService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class SubscriberController {

    private SubscriberService subscriberService;

    @Autowired
    public void setSubscriberService(SubscriberService subscriberService) {
        this.subscriberService = subscriberService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView allSubs() {
        List<Subscriber> subscribers = subscriberService.allSubs();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("subscribers");
        modelAndView.addObject("subscriberList", subscribers);
        return modelAndView;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editPage(@PathVariable int id) {
        Subscriber subscriber = subscriberService.getById(id);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("editPage");
        modelAndView.addObject("subscriber", subscriber);
        return modelAndView;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView editSubscriber(@ModelAttribute("subscriber") Subscriber subscriber) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/");
        subscriberService.edit(subscriber);
        return modelAndView;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("addPage");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addSubscriber(@ModelAttribute("subscriber") Subscriber subscriber) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/");
        subscriberService.add(subscriber);
        return modelAndView;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteSubscriber(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/");
        Subscriber film = subscriberService.getById(id);
        subscriberService.delete(film);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Вебконфиг:

```
package borkaugroup.phonedirectory.config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("borkaugroup.phonedirectory")
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Глагна:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Subscribers</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Subscribers</h2>
<form method="get" action="search">
    <input type="text" name="keyword" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>name</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="subscriber" items="${subscriberList}">
        <tr>
            <td>${subscriber.id}</td>
            <td>${subscriber.phone}</td>
            <td>${subscriber.name}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="/edit/${subscriber.id}">edit</a>
                <a href="/delete/${subscriber.id}">delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

<h2>Add</h2>
<c:url value="/add" var="add"/>
<a href="${add}">Add new subscriber</a>
</body>
</html>
```

И сам *editPage.jsp*

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit subscriber</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:url value="/edit" var="var"/>
<form action="${var}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${subscriber.id}">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit subscriber">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может ошибка тут

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Когда работает

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Можно попробовать

```
         @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Разница а методе запроса GET и POST

Comment: Да не, это же стандартные запроса и передачи данных. Сначала мы должны получить страницу с редактором, а потом передать данные. Да, у меня есть подозрение, что я маппинг неправильно сделал, но не могу понять как сделать правильно.